# Formulas not automatically calculating in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My Excel spreadsheets only calculate the formulas once you hit save. I know I can change this setting under Option > Formulas > Workbook calculation (automatic). However, every time I re-open the file it reverts back to the manual calculation method.

Can someone please advise how I can make it automatically calculate as the default setting?

Comment: If possible please share the WB with us on cloud so that we can examine it,,, it's unusual activity !!